# How to solve import() (prev. System.import()) syntax error in eslint?

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

As of webpack 2 non-beta, `import()` is the syntax for the old `System.import()`. While this works, eslint even at latest version still throws a linting syntax error:

```
[js] Expression or comma expected.
(method) import(): any
```

Are we in this can be solved zones yet?

Answer (score 1):

The default parser used by eslint does not yet include the dynamic `import()` syntax. You can use `babel-eslint` as a parser, which allows you to use everything that is understood by babel.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
```

In your `.eslintrc` configure the `parser` option ([ESLint - Specifying Parser](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser)).

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

Babel itself needs [babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) to understand the dynamic import syntax. If you're already using babel to transpile your code, you should already have that.